# Environment variables vs build configurations for .NET Core configuration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

what is better to use for configuring .net core application for development and production environments: environment variables or build configurations? I.e. I can bound `appsettings.*environment*.json` to both of this ways

Comment: The reason both exist is that both have advantages and disadvantages. Asking "which is better" doesn't make much sense. Maybe ask for pros/cons of both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build configurations are a hold-over from the .NET Framework days. While you can somewhat use them in a .NET Core application, their utility is limited. About the only use is directives where you do something like:

```
#if DEBUG
// stuff
#endif
```

However, that's a questionable practice, to begin with.

With .NET Core, the paradigm is that you publish once for all environments. The concept of an environment is independent of the code itself, as it should be. This ensures that your code actually works as it should as you graduate from dev/test to staging/QA, and finally to production because the code is the code.

That aside, and since you're specifically asking about configuration, build-based config doesn't work in .NET Core. There is no app.config/web.config, and even when there is a web.config, specifically to support hosting in IIS, it's not actually utilized by .NET Core in any way - just IIS.

As such, the question is moot. For configuration in .NET Core, you use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, which itself relies on the concept of the environment also being config-based, rather than build-based. You don't *have* to an environment variable, actually. The environment can be passed through the command line, as well. The point is that it's set a run-time, not compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your view of the progression through environments.

If its build config, then you've got a 'different' executable per environment, as your rebuilding it for each, so you've not tested exactly what you will actually deploy to production.